# Need explanation for a macro expansion in C++

Tags: c++, macros

```
#define PRINT(str,...) printf("%s:%d "  str, __FUNCTION__, __LINE__, ##__VA_ARGS__)
```

This macro in c++ seems to output function and line followed by the str params is provided. For example, calling like the following,

```
13 void func(){
14    PRINT("Hello %s", "World");
15 }
```

outputs,

> "func:14 Hello World"

My question is why `str` in the macro is not being treated as the first value for the placeholder '%s' even though I am placing `str` in the first place?

What happens when we expand the macro PRINT for the given example?

Comment: You are imagining a comma where there isn't one. The `str` argument is concatenated onto the format string by the compiler.

Comment: @Botje but we did not concat them explicitly by `##`. What's the rule for that to happen?

Comment: @SazzadHissainKhan, It happens after preprocessing and before compilation as its own phase of translation.

Comment: `##` is used to concatenate (also called token pasting) identifier fragments.  A `"string"` is not an identifier fragment.  You can `"con" "cat" "ten" "ate"` string literals by juxtaposition.  (The term *identifier fragments* is my own terminology.  The documentation just calls each part an *identifier*.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In

```
"%s:%d "  str
```

Both `"%s:%d "` and `str` are string literals with `str` being `"Hello %s"`.  Since they are adjacent string literals, the preprocessos concatenates those literals together and the `printf` resolves to

```
printf("%s:%d Hello %s", __FUNCTION__, __LINE__, "world")
```